# Automation commits from Google code to Github

Tags: git, github, synchronization, google-code

I have a project on **Google code**: [Project on Google code](https://code.google.com/p/code--review/). Resently, I exported it to **GitHub**: [Project on GitHub](https://github.com/VeLKerr/code--review).

How I can automate sending commits from **Google code** to **GitHub**?
I.e. I want to continue working with Google code, but all new commits should be authomatically sent to the GitHub repo? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
google code doesnt belong to you, what you have access to is your github repo. so clone the repo on your computer.

    1.git clone https://github.com/VeLKerr/code--review.git

    2.try add a new file say test.foo in that same directory on your computer

    3. git add --all

    4.git commit -am "Testing Foo"

    5. git push origin master

That should solve it.
```